# can I send SAML request to IDp without register service provider into IDp

Tags: java, saml-2.0, federation

I mean to say,  can I send SAML request to IDp without register service provider into IDp ??
my employer want to develop one sample application in JAVA with service provider and identity provider,so service provider will send SAML 2.0 authrequest  request/respond to identity provider.
so i have downloaded sample appliaction from [this link](http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/tree/master/sample).this example will use **ssocircle** as idp and its working fine.

here we have to import metadata in ssocircle idp for service provider.But here my employer don't want to service provider to depend on IDP.So basically he want service provider to communicate with any IDP with SAML2.0 request and service provider should not be depend on IDP .service provider will send authrequest to any idp and idp will give the respond. 
and how we can send request to IDP in java ,if you can provide and sample application link.

Comment: You can look at  http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/

Comment: Information you provided is not enough to provide solution, try post what you have did so far, there lot of openSAML library out there to make saml request to idp but as far as I know you must register your Sp with idp to make proper sso this were the proper security comes in.

Comment: I would suggest adding more content to this question, to help us get to the answer that you need to resolve this problem. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and review your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible when IdP and SP are within same security-domain, where two are intrinsically trusted and their public-key materials are available by each other to understand and process the SAML AuthnRequest and Response.

Ideally, SAML protocol requires trust establishment between IdP and SP, where these two resides in different security-domains.

But for your requirement, I suggest to use OpenID or OAuth protocol, where SP won't depend on any particular IdP.

Comment: @@Zeigest can please provide any sample application link...basically how to start. Currently i am using SSOCIRCLE public IDP but when  i need to start for enterprise then how to start from scratch.

Comment: I don't have any links. Your requirement only work when you have both IdP and SP internally within same security domain. If you choose external IdP like SSOCircle and your app, an SP is somewhere, then the above said solution impossible without exchanging the metadata between IdP and SP. For your requirement, I suggest use OpenID or OAuth protocol.